# How to Start and Stop Appium Server programmatically using Python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, appium

I am a newbie to Python and have created simple Appium Automation Test case for Android mobile app.

I have setup Jenkins server and want to run Appium on it so there are 2 ways:

1. Run appium server via Jenkins (We can run it using `appium` command but when I run appium command it just "hangs up" and showing server console continiously)
2. Start Appium Server programmatically using Python

I know we can [run Appium Server programmatically using Java](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver/wiki/How-to-start-an-AppiumDriver-locally) but don't know about python.

So, if you have any idea about either of above 2 ways, please post the answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer for 1:

Use `appium &` command.

Use **&** at the end of the command that will run it in background and didn't freeze the terminal.

Please Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650509/multiple-terminal-window-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

Below is what you can do for 2. Start Appium Server programmatically using Python

```
import os

#starts appium on same terminal window

os.system("appium")

#starts appium on new terminal window 
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k appium")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is:

write `appium` in terminal

or if I want a specific chromedriver version then I do:

```
appium --chromedriver-executable /path/to/my/chromedriver/chromedriver_2.42
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a shell script called startAppium.sh with this command: appium --debug &

2) Create a shell script called killAppium.sh with this command: kill $(ps -e | grep 'appium' | awk '{print $1}')

3) Use python to run either process to execute the shell scripts: 
import killProcess 
killProcess.call(['./killAppium.sh'])

Note: I use the above for Jenkins CI/CD in the groovy file's setup and post blocks with just the commands, i.e: sh "appium --debug &" and sh "kill $(ps -e | grep 'appium' | awk '{print $1}')".